# Hosting Google Plus Communities on My Website

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to embed a google community into a website page?

This way our clients can benefit from content and all other features in our website, yet be able to collaborate using Google Communities.

Ideally I would like to grab a Javascript code just like +1 button and paste it into my website page, add an iframe or something of this nature!

**UPDATE:**

Sounds like if I try to be convincing, I may be able to influence some decisions!
More details: Our website services offers login with Google using Google OAuth, This way the user is either logged in or is forced to login with Google to get access to private areas of our customer portal, where you can review the status of Support Tickets, submit new support tickets, have access to knowledge base, documents, blogs, etc.

We have incorporated all sort of social plugins into the blogs, product catalogs and so forth.
It would be fantastic is the users can have access to a community (Forum or Discussion Board) within the same place. Google Community seem to be the tool but in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such widget exists at this time, but it's an interesting idea. If you want to share more details on precisely what you're looking for, you can file the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/. The more details you can provide, the more likely that, if we decide to implement this feature, we'll end up with something that you want.